# PHP - How to remove duplicate values from array (compare 2 arrays)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, duplicates

I would like to remove values from the `$allPermissions` array that are in the `$userPermissions` array.

How to do it? I've already combined `array_unique`, `array_diff`, and I still have not come to solve this problem. Someone something?

```
public function notAssigned($id, Request $request)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $userPermissions = [{"id":5,"name":"create post","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2018-12-22 02:44:35","updated_at":"2018-12-22 02:44:35","pivot":{"model_id":3,"permission_id":5,"model_type":"App\\User"}}];
    $allPermissions = [{"id":5,"name":"create post","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2018-12-22 02:44:35","updated_at":"2018-12-22 02:44:35"},{"id":6,"name":"edit post","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2018-12-22 02:44:46","updated_at":"2018-12-22 02:44:46"},{"id":7,"name":"delete post","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2018-12-22 02:44:59","updated_at":"2018-12-22 02:44:59"}];

    $permissions = array_unique(array_merge($userPermissions, $allPermissions));
    $role = auth()->user()->hasRole([2]);
    $permission = auth()->user()->can('edit user permission');

    if ( $role == true || $permission == true ) {
        return $permissions;
    } else {
        abort(403, 'Access Denied');
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Those are the output of `var_dump` to `$userPermissions` and `$allPermissionsallPermissions`:

```
var_dump($userPermissions):

    array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#361 (6) { ["id"]=> int(5) ["name"]=> string(11) "create post" ["guard_name"]=> string(3) "web" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2018-12-22 02:44:35" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2018-12-22 02:44:35" ["pivot"]=> object(stdClass)#360 (3) { ["model_id"]=> int(3) ["permission_id"]=> int(5) ["model_type"]=> string(8) "App\User" } } }

var_dump($allPermissions):

    array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#374 (5) { ["id"]=> int(5) ["name"]=> string(11) "create post" ["guard_name"]=> string(3) "web" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2018-12-22 02:44:35" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2018-12-22 02:44:35" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#377 (5) { ["id"]=> int(6) ["name"]=> string(9) "edit post" ["guard_name"]=> string(3) "web" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2018-12-22 02:44:46" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2018-12-22 02:44:46" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#376 (5) { ["id"]=> int(7) ["name"]=> string(11) "delete post" ["guard_name"]=> string(3) "web" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2018-12-22 02:44:59" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2018-12-22 02:44:59" } }
```

Comment: `$allPermissions = [{"..."}];` this is not proper PHP array syntax.  It looks like some weird combination of JSON in an array.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I get such an array from the built-in function in Spatie\permissions. How to make an array from this?

Comment: Instead try this `$userPermissions = json_decode('{"id":5,"name":"create post",...}', true);`  I don't know how else you could do it, what you have is a compiler error for PHP, meaning it wont even finish parsing this file let alone run it.  But without seeing exactly what that "stuff" is all I can do is extrapolate.
    `

Comment: $userPermissions = json_decode($user->permissions[0], true);
returns
{"id":5,"name":"create post", ... ,"pivot":{"model_id":3,"permission_id":5,"model_type":"App\\User"}}

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix
I did the same for $allPermissions and I did array_unique (array_merge ($userPermissions, $allPermissions))
and I get an error for this function: "Array to string conversion". After decoding json, I do not have arrays, so how can I delete repeating elements now?

Comment: As I said without me seeing exactly what `$userPermissions` is I cant tell you, there is a big difference between  `['{"id":6, ... }']` and `'[{"id":6, ... }]'`  One is an array the other a string, I have no idea what you have except what you posted, `[{"id":5,...}]` which is syntactically incorrect in PHP (so it cant be that or it wouldn't be in a variable)

Comment: please `dd($userPermissions);` after initializing it and post the output, same goes for $allPermissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your array are valid you can use [array-filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for that:

```
$userP = '[{"id":5,"name":"create post","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2018-12-22 02:44:35","updated_at":"2018-12-22 02:44:35"}]';
$userPermissions = json_decode($userP, true); // will convert to array.

$allP = '[{"id":5,"name":"create post","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2018-12-22 02:44:35","updated_at":"2018-12-22 02:44:35"},{"id":6,"name":"edit post","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2018-12-22 02:44:46","updated_at":"2018-12-22 02:44:46"},{"id":7,"name":"delete post","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2018-12-22 02:44:59","updated_at":"2018-12-22 02:44:59"}]';
$allPermissions = json_decode($allP , true); // will convert to array.

$userPermissionIds = array_column($userPermissions, "id")
$filteredPermission = array_filter($allPermissions , function($elem) use ($userPermissionIds) {
    return !in_array($elem["id"], $userPermissionIds);
});
```

This will result with `$filteredPermission` to contain only element that no exist in the user permission array

**Edited**: If you want to stay with your array of object you can use:

```
$userPermissionIds = array();
foreach($userPermissions as $per)
    $userPermissionIds[] = $per->id;

$filteredPermission = array_filter($allPermissions , function($elem) use ($userPermissionIds) {
    return !in_array($elem->id, $userPermissionIds);
});
```

Comment: For the $userPermissions variable, I dynamically enter data using "$user-> permissions;" and then after checking the $userPermissions variable, I have in it: [{"id": 5, "name": "create post", ..., "pivot": {"model_id": 3, "permission_id": 5, " model_type ":" \\ app User "}}]. After using your solution I get the error: "array_column () expects parameter 1 to be array, object given".

Comment: Whereas $ userPermissions = [$user-> permissions]; $allPermissions = [Permission :: get ()]; I'm getting an "Undefined index: id" error

Comment: @MateuszDomurad that because your arrays are array of object and not array of arrays. converting the those objects to array (by using json_decode with true as second parameter) will allow you to use the simple code I posted. If you want to keep them as object please post the var dump (examples) of both arrays and I will update my answer

Comment: I posted var dumps :)

Comment: but how do you get out of this using foreach eg id?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I would like to draw from this table, for example, all IDs using foreach

Comment: @foreach( $permissions as $permission ) <tr><th scope="row">{{ $permission -> id }}</th></tr> @endforeach

Comment: What you wrote seems ok - try to put it on context. If you involve accessing it with HTML I think you should open new question for that as it not seems related to current post

Comment: Okay. I'm wrote new post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53903984/php-how-to-extract-data-from-this-table